# When did Jack Swigert realize that he forgot to file his taxes?

Tags: astronauts, apollo-13, space-taxes

As portrayed in the film *Apollo 13*, astronaut Jack Swigert forgot to file his taxes:

> JACK SWIGERT: Well uh, if anyone from the IRS is watching, I forgot to
>   file my 1040 return and I meant to do it today but...
>
> SY LIEBERGOT (EECOM - WHITE): That's no joke! They'll jump on him!

**In real life, when did Jack Swigert realize that he forgot to file his taxes?**  A complete answer will include the calendar date, mission time, and the relevant dialogue (*especially the funny parts*).

It's worth noting that in 1970, the deadline to file taxes was April 15.

*This question is part of a series honoring the 50th anniversary of Apollo 13, "NASA's finest hour".*

Comment: I thought "space-taxes" was an appropriate tag.

Comment: I don't have a source to check for 1970, but at least as early as 1985 there was an automatic 2-month filing extension "if you are living or traveling outside the US and Puerto Rico on (tax day)".

Comment: This question is also part of a series honoring IRS deadlines ..

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thank you, I never understood the line in the movie when this is brought up, someone reassures him by saying something like "you're decidedly out of the country". I never knew why that would make any difference for the filing requirement.

Comment: @StarMan apparently a popular idea, considering "space-taxes" was also an issue in ''Deep Impact''. :)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Jack Swigert realized that he forgot to pay his taxes around the first hour of the second day. Here's the dialogue from [the Apollo 13 transcript](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a13/AS13_TEC.PDF): Note, Jack Swigert is the CMP (Command Module Pilot), Jim Lovell is the CDR (Commander), and Joseph Peter Kerwin is the CC (CAPCOM, crew members just call him Joe).

[image]

So I guess the answer to your question: He realized he forgot to pay his taxes at 1:00:18 which was on April 12, 1970 around 2:31 PM EST. It's not surprising given the fact that everyone pays their taxes last minute, and Jack Swigert unexpectedly came onboard Apollo 13 (he was a backup).